# XSLT script to match pattern a particular element instance within a specific parent Complextype

Tags: xslt

I have a schema which is something like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.28.0">  
  <xsd:complexType name="AccountsReceivableInfo_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
      <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="AccountsDeleteInfo_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
      <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

and I am trying to modify it and write an XSLT script to:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.28.0">  
  <xsd:complexType name="AccountsReceivableInfo_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <!--<xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>-->  
      <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="AccountsDeleteInfo_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
      <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

XSLT script which i wrote so far is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="xsd:complexType[@name='AccountsReceivableInfo_Type']
/xsd:element[@ref ='SourceIncomePct']">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
     <xsl:sequence select="."/>
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

What I am trying to do is to modify a big schema like above and automate it and need to read a particular element within a particular complextype parent and modify only that instance like commenting it out.

Comment: And what output does this give? (disable-output-escaping might or might not work depending on the phase of the moon. More specifically, it works if (a) the processor chooses to support it, and (b) the transformation is run in a way that generates serialized output).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the element into a comment consider to move to XSLT 3.0 and use

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:complexType[@name='AccountsReceivableInfo_Type']/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@ref ='SourceIncomePct']">
  <xsl:comment select="serialize(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```